# FxCop fails to analyse the indirectly referenced assembly

Tags: .net-assembly, fxcop, metrics

Metrics.exe: error: The referenced assembly 'Exception.dll, version=1.0.5289.9, Culture=neutral, publickeytoken=67er8..' could not be found. This assembly is required for analysis and was referenced by 
\bin\cancel.dll.

But the assembly it is trying to refer to (Exception.dll) is GAC'd. i.e, present in the C:\windows\assembly.

I have around 300 project files.. Copying the assembly to each project will be a cumbersome process..

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Important: Check the assembly versions.

The assembly Exception.dll was of an older version in GAC. But the assemblies trying to refer this assembly was of another version. Simply GACd the newer version of the assembly - Exception.dll in the GAC and it worked :-)